# How to add titles in the leaderboard? ROBLOX LUA

Tags: lua, roblox, leaderboard

So in the leaderboard I have cash, exp, etc. But I also want to have a "Title" option, the thing is that if I want to change the stat, I dont know how to change it to words instead of numbers, can anyone help me?

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: Not sure what code to provide, maybe

 local Title = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
 
 Title.Name = "Title"

And I would like the stat value to be like "Starter" and also make it appear above your character
(sorry for not adding code format idk how since Im new at the page)

Comment: @RevelMind Forgot to answer but thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

What you'd be looking for is a `StringValue`.  These can store strings of text instead of numbers, booleans, etc.

```lua
local stringValue = Instance.new("StringValue", [player].leaderstats)
stringValue.Value = "Your text here"
```